# p:gmap won't show

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-gmap

I am using PrimeFaces GMap to display a map.

I have tried the simplest possible solution.

I have taken the key from Google and written code like this:

```
<h:head>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyASp910hdK6GE2OeqQCEmmsL5bE2srrviI" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Admin</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div>
            <p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID" style="width:100%;height:400px" />
        </div>
......
```

I have tried with multiples keys.

I have tried with `async`, `defer`, `?sensor=false`, etc.

Nothing seems to work; the map just won't show.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Did you ask this question before?

Comment: No, i didn't. It's my first time working with JSF and primefaces on a school project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is happening because you did not include the Google Map script in your `<head>` tag. PrimeFaces showcase should warn users about this...

Include this following script in your `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

**IMPORTANT: If you are using localhost, the map will still not work. You must either use an IP (can be 127.0.0.1, for example) or host your application in any cloud**.

**IMPORTANT²: Since 2016 Google Maps also require an API key to work properly, you can read more about it [here](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html).**

Comment: I have included it, along with the key as you can see in my code. Still won't work tho.

Comment: Try removing any additional code in your page then. I just ran a new application with PrimeFaces 6.0 with only the gmap component and everything worked fine. Probably there are more code in your application that may be causiing this problem.

Comment: U were right, i just made a new empty xhtml page with only the map component and it worked. You have any idea on how to pinpoint whats been blocking it on the other page? Thanks tho!

Comment: My guess is that you have one or more components with a broken JavaScript code. To pinpoint this just open your browser's developer console and look for JavaScript errors logged there.